# wcout в WinXP при использовании MinGW w64

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, mingw

Как вывести не-ASCII текст с помощью `std::wcout` в Windows XP, если для компиляции используется MinGW w64? Уже посмотрел кучу похожих вопросов, но ничего из этого не работает. `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT)` возвращает -1, компиляция с `-municode` не помогает — сообщение печатается до первого не-ASCII символа. (полная команда: `i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -mconsole -municode -static`). С другой стороны, вот такой код:

```
int wmain() {
    DWORD _;
    std::wstring ws = L"кошка\n";
    WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), ws.c_str(), ws.size(), &_, nullptr);
    return 0;
}
```

выводит сообщение правильно, но мне хотелось бы использовать wcout. Может быть, есть способ?

Answer (score 1):

Временное решение: написать свои классы-наследники `std::wstreambuf`, которые бы выводили строки через `WriteConsoleW` и считывали через `ReadConsoleW`. Потом объекты этих классов можно поместить в `wcout` и в `wcin` и тогда они будут работать с не-ASCII текстом правильно.

Этот код можно поместить в .cpp файл и просто добавить к проекту.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>

class MyWriteBuf:public std::wstreambuf{
public:
    MyWriteBuf(DWORD handle):std::wstreambuf(), _handle(handle){
    }
protected:
    virtual std::streamsize xsputn(const wchar_t* s, std::streamsize num) override {
        std::copy(s, s + num,
                  std::back_inserter(_buffer));
        return num;
    }
    virtual int sync() override {
        if (!_buffer.empty()) {
            std::wstring str(_buffer.cbegin(), _buffer.cend());
            DWORD _;
            WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(_handle), str.c_str(), str.size(), &_, nullptr);
            _buffer.clear();
        }
        return 0;
    }
private:
    DWORD _handle;
    std::vector<wchar_t> _buffer;
};

class MyReadBuf:public std::wstreambuf{
public:
    MyReadBuf():std::wstreambuf(){
        setg(_chars, _chars+BUF_SIZE, _chars+BUF_SIZE);
    }
protected:
    int_type underflow() override {
        DWORD num_read;
        ReadConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), _chars, BUF_SIZE, &num_read, nullptr);
        setg(_chars, _chars, _chars+num_read);
        return (int_type)(_chars[0]);
    }
private:
    const static uint8_t BUF_SIZE=10;
    wchar_t _chars[BUF_SIZE];
};

int static_init(){
    MyWriteBuf *buf_out=new MyWriteBuf(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    MyWriteBuf *buf_err=new MyWriteBuf(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
    MyReadBuf *buf_in=new MyReadBuf();
    std::wcout.rdbuf(buf_out);
    std::wcerr.rdbuf(buf_err);
    std::wcin.rdbuf(buf_in);
    return 0;
}

int global_t=static_init();
```